# recorded .jmx file in badboy software not working in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded script in Badboy software and save this exported this file with option as export to Jmeter in `.jmx` extension but now i am not able to open this file and getting below error message in JMeter:

> Problem loading XML from:'C:\JMeter\Badboy Script\MySecondUITest.jmx'.
> Cause:
> CannotResolveClassException: node
>
> Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: node

Comment: Which jmeter version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into 2nd line of the .jmx file, you should see something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.1.1 r1855137">
```

For me it's latest version of JMeter which is [JMeter 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html). You should be able to determine the relevant JMeter version and download it from [JMeter Archives](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/) area

---

Actually I don't think that using Badboy for recording JMeter tests is the best idea, http://www.badboy.com.au website doesn't even work and the latest Badboy release is dated 2011 year

So I would recommend either using JMeter's built-in [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) or if you have issues with it although it should work just fine [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

most probably the export feature of Badboy does not support your version of JMeter.

Which version of badboy and jmeter are you using ?

Note that if you use Badboy for recording, you can use directly this feature into JMeter with recording template:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html