# Jmeter fails to open .jmx file created by Badboy

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

When i tried to open a jmx file in Jmeter created by Badboy, Jmeter throws this error:

[image]

Here is the log file :

```
2019-12-14 12:21:36,712 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: C:\Users\hp\Documents\MyFirstJMeterScript.jmx
2019-12-14 12:21:36,772 WARN o.a.j.g.a.Load: Unexpected error. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'C:\Users\hp\Documents\MyFirstJMeterScript.jmx'. 
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: node

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: node
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'C:\Users\hp\Documents\MyFirstJMeterScript.jmx'. 
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: node

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: node
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:459) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:432) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:130) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doActionAfterCheck(Load.java:89) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391) [?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: node
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService$XStreamWrapper$1.realClass(SaveService.java:98) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:133) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1487) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1467) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1338) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:449) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    ... 20 more
2019-12-14 12:24:24,785 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Load: Loading file: C:\Users\hp\Documents\MyFirstJMeterScript.jmx
2019-12-14 12:24:24,786 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Users\hp\Documents'
2019-12-14 12:24:24,786 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: C:\Users\hp\Documents\MyFirstJMeterScript.jmx
2019-12-14 12:24:24,881 WARN o.a.j.g.a.Load: Unexpected error. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'C:\Users\hp\Documents\MyFirstJMeterScript.jmx'. 
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: node

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: node
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'C:\Users\hp\Documents\MyFirstJMeterScript.jmx'. 
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: node

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: node
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:459) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:432) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:130) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doActionAfterCheck(Load.java:89) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391) [?:?]
```

Comment: Seems like you have a jmeter version mismatch. What version of jmeter badboy using? Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638419/recorded-jmx-file-in-badboy-software-not-working-in-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using Badboy (whatever it is) is the best approach to create a JMeter test script. Looking into your error details:

> CannotResolveClassException: node

I recall the fact that the last JMeter version which was able to open JMeter test plans starting from `<node>` was [JMeter 2.13](https://www.blazemeter.com/jmeter-213/)

If you **really** need to open the .jmx script recorded by Badboy you need to [get JMeter 2.13](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.13.zip)

However be informed that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so if you can re-record your test scenario, it's better to stick to the latest stable version of JMeter and use [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

Answer (score 0):

you may try installing jmeter [plugin manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/) and add it in lib/ext folder. hope that works for you.

Comment: The link is for jar files so I have added it and it is from exclusive apache jmeter website which is included in jmeter package only.